# android studio webview Fragment "Uncaught TypeError: $(...).dialog is not a function"

Tags: android, android-studio, fragment

need help,
my code working fine on

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final WebView myWebView1 = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    WebSettings webSettings1 = myWebView1.getSettings();
    webSettings1.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    myWebView1.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    myWebView1.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    myWebView1.loadUrl("https://example.com");
}}
```

But generate error when i use in Fragment

```
public class ReportSales01Activity extends Fragment{
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_report_sales_01, container, false);

        final WebView myWebView1 = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        WebSettings webSettings1 = myWebView1.getSettings();
        webSettings1.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        myWebView1.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        myWebView1.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        myWebView1.loadUrl("https://example.com");
        return view;}}
```

the error message

> I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(313)] "Uncaught TypeError: $(...).dialog is not a function", source: http://example.com (313)

Can some help me solving this issue.

Comment: `dialog()` is not a standard jQuery method. Presumably you need to include jQueryUI in your project; or any other library which includes a `dialog()` plugin

Comment: the code working fine, but not in Fragment

Answer (score 1):

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).dialog is not a function

Enable **`.setDomStorageEnabled(true);` `.setDatabaseEnabled(true)`**

```
public class ReportSales01Activity extends Fragment
{

        @Nullable
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) 
         {
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_report_sales_01, container, false);

                final WebView myWebView1 = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.webView1);
                WebSettings webSettings1 = myWebView1.getSettings();
                webSettings1.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                webSettings1.setDomStorageEnabled(true);// Add this 
                webSettings1.setDatabaseEnabled(true);// Add this 
                myWebView1.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
                myWebView1.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
                myWebView1.loadUrl("https://example.com");
                return view;
         }
    }
```

Comment: same result as before

Comment: I am also getting same results too.